# How to check an array inside json data is empty using jmespath?

Tags: javascript, json, jmespath

I have json data as below:

```
[
  {
    "id": "i_1",
    "name": "abc",
    "address": [
      {
        "city": [
          "city1",
          "city2"
        ]
      },
      {
        "city": [
          "city1",
          "city2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "i_2",
    "name": "def",
    "address": [
      {
        "city": []
      },
      {
        "city": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now, I want only that data where `city` array is not `null`. So in the above example the output should be 1st element i.e. with id `i_1`.

How to filter this `json` using [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/) library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "id": "i_1",
    "name": "abc",
    "address": [
      {
        "city": [
          "city1",
          "city2"
        ]
      },
      {
        "city": [
          "city1",
          "city2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "i_2",
    "name": "def",
    "address": [
      {
        "city": []
      },
      {
        "city": []
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(jmespath.search(arr,"[?not_null(address[].city[])]"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jmespath/0.15.0/jmespath.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in pure javascript using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
const items=[{"id":"i_1","name":"abc","address":[{"city":["city1","city2"]},{"city":["city1","city2"]}]},{"id":"i_2","name":"def","address":[{"city":[]},{"city":[]}]}]

const filtered = items.filter(i => i.address.every(a => a.city && a.city.length > 0))

console.log(filtered)
```

This returns only if *every* object inside `address` has a non-empty city array.

Comment: I want to do this using  jmespath, is there any way to do this using  jmespath?

Comment: you could simplify this a little by changing `a.city.length > 0` to just `a.city.length`

Comment: @MonarthSarvaiya I don't know, sorry. Just providing an alternative javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use **jmespath library** use `filter` and `every from the vanilla JS. It is more efficient.

```js
let jsonTxt = '{"data":[{"id":"i_1","name":"abc","address":[{"city":["city1","city2"]},{"city":["city1","city2"]}]},{"id":"i_2","name":"def","address":[{"city":[]},{"city":[]}]}]}'

let jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonTxt);
let items = jsonData.data;
const result = items.filter(i => i.address.every(a => a.city && a.city.length))
console.log('id: ', result[0].id);
//using jmespath
console.log(jmespath.search({data: items}, "data[*].address[*].city"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jmespath/0.15.0/jmespath.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using other filters of jmespath, at this point I am stuck, so I want solution only using jmespath. Here is only some part of my code.